# Why my wordpress site asks for http authentication?

Tags: wordpress, basic-authentication

When I upload all my wordpress site files to live using ftp. And changed the `siteurl` and `sitehome` options from the `wp_options` table. I disabled all plugins as well.

The front-end worked fine. But when I try to access wp-admin a browser popup apears asking username and password as in the picture. 
There is no config for Http authentication in .htaccess file.

.htaccess content

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain, what settings I need to change. its shared hosting. @David

Comment: its probably set in apache config, contact the hosting provider, i doubt you will have the auth to change it!

Comment: Another website in the same directory working file. That is also wordpress

Comment: well its not a wp process and not your .htaccess so not much anyone can do for you based on the information posted, its doubtful any theme or plugin is changing apache settings, so its still a case of checking with your hosting provider, most of them are happy enough to offer tech support.

Comment: All plugins are disabled.

Comment: Looks like a .htpasswd file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htpasswd) in the root of your site - check the contents of the folders and if you can see anything check with your host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Some hosting providers](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/wordpress-brute-force/) use [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on default CMS's login pages, like

```
host/wp-admin
host/administrator
```

to prevent brute force attacks on them. The major advantage of this solution is moving the load generated by brute force attacks from PHP engine to the server application (Apache).

Usually credentials for the http authentication are provided on the popup itself. As they are not provided in your case, contacting your hosting provider is the way to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem on our website [Saglotech](https://www.saglotech.co.za/). This is how we fixed it. Inside your .htacces, add these lines:

```
<filesmatch "wp-login.php">
Satisfy Any
</filesmatch>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Worked for me in 2021. Awesome answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use this code , wordpress asking for ftp details because wordpress doesn't have permission to write in your server.
use these two commands in terminal.

```
$sudo a2enmod rewrite

$sudo chown -R www-data /var/www
```

video guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGGWVUIvhnk